# Unresolved external symbol displayed as an error while /force:unresolved is used

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker, unresolved-external

Is there a way to change the severity of the LNK2001 log (let say from error to warning), or even avoid this log, when /force:unresolved flag is used at link time ?

Basically, I want to force the generation of a dll (with a undefined symbol, let say "X") and delay the symbol resolution at executable link time (where the executable is linked with the "forced" dll and another one which contains the "X" symbol).

Answer (score 1):

[From documentation of /FORCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx):

> /FORCE:UNRESOLVED is ignored if the entry point symbol is unresolved

So check that your DLL has an [entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is an undocumented option to switch off some linker [warnings](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/link/link/options/ignore.htm), but not for errors.